# using arrays to query with SELECT with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm querying a table that returns id's and I'd like to use these id's within an array to perform another query.

I have the two queries working independently of each other by hard coding the id's into the second query just to be sure that it functions as expected, which it does.

```
$query = "SELECT item_id FROM items"; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE results_item_id in (1,2,3,4)";
```

I'd like the return of the second query to include data for all of the id's returned to me from the first query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of sub query, you can do it by `JOIN` matching `ON item_id = results_item_id`

```
$query = "SELECT R.* FROM results R JOIN items I ON I.item_id = R.results_item_id";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the query inside the `IN`, and add distinct so each item_id you only get in once:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE results_item_id in (SELECT distinct item_id FROM items)";
```